# Trying to send a http get request from a php file to a server and receive a http response

Tags: php, curl, get, httprequest, httpresponse

I'm trying to send a http get request in a php file to a server and receive the response.

```
function broadcastRequest($catCommand,$command,$prop){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'http://'.$prop["ipServer"].':'.$prop["portVLM"].$prop["startURL"].$catCommand."%20".$prop["broadcastName"].'%20'.$command);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    $res = curl_exec ($ch);
    $res = simplexml_load_file($res);   
    curl_close ($ch);
}
```

- If I echo the first `$res` I can read the number 1
- the second `$res` won't load because `simplexml_load_file()` isn't syntax-highlighted in my Notepad++

Can someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong, or advise another way of working?

Comment: Try `print_r($res);` and write here result

Comment: Don't worry about symtax highlighting!I'm pretty sure this function exists ;) 
If PHP tells you it's undefined, maybe you have to allow SimpleXML PHP extension, but I thing its included in the core now (not sure of that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to set the CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER option. However, it's probably easier to just do this:

```
$res = file_get_contents($uri);
```

Comment: file_get_content was indeed an much easier solution, i tested it, but still not getting the a response.. i used print_r and echo.. wish printed nothing.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Notepad++'s syntax highlighting has *absolutely nothing to do* with whether it's valid. It just reads names, and you'll notice that `simplexml_load_file` is never highlighted.

Now onto the problem. `$res` is just a boolean value returned by [`curl_exec`](http://php.net/curl_exec), because you haven't set the `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` option, as specified in the docs. However, a simpler way is just loading it directly:

```
function broadcastRequest($catCommand,$command,$prop) {
    $res = simplexml_load_file('http://' . $prop["ipServer"] . ':' . $prop["portVLM"] . $prop["startURL"] . $catCommand . '%20' . $prop["broadcastName"] . '%20' . $command);
}
```

If you'd like to use cURL, however, just set the additional option:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
```